# Startup problem with Ubuntu/windows8.1

Tags: grub2

So I installed Ubuntu last night and I have gnu grub 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.6 my laptop is a Toshiba with core i3 processor and it has windows 8.1 or had windows, when u get to the start up screen it has the Ubuntu and it has the windows boot manager (on /Dev/sda2) path when I click on the windows one it says /EndEntire and just won't load up but the Ubuntu one works fine how can I get both startups to work any answeres??

I need the windows to work becuase of some games I acquired I just want windows so as to avoid buying the games again